# Proving a product is real based on two given complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

We have two numbers $z=4e^{5\pi i/3}$ and $w=3e^{2\pi i/3}.$

Let $u$ be a complex number such that $u^2 = w.$

- Prove that $z \times u$ is real.

---

### Attempt:

1. I thought one way is give $u$ an algebraic form and establish two equations for its real and imaginary parts based on $u^2 = w$. So $u = a + ib$, and we get $a^2 - b^2 = -3/2$ and $2ab = 3\sqrt{3}/2.$ Then we can solve for $a,b.$
2. Alternatively, we can start with the calculation of the imaginary part of $z \times u$ directly: i.e., $$ \frac{z u - \bar{z}\bar{u}}{2i} =c \tag{1}$$ and to show $c$ is zero. But I get stuck quickly after $z u - \bar{z}\bar{u} = 2c i$ and multiplying by $\bar{u}$:

$$
z w - \bar{z}|u|^2 = 2c i u \tag{2}
$$

But we still have a $u$ on the rhs, and I don't know how to make progress towards showing $c=0$ from here.

---

### Question:

- Which of the two approaches is more fitting here? Any hints as to how to make progress where I am stuck would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Show that $z^2u^2$ is real and positive.

Comment: Cool idea! So with the idea to show at the end that if $z^2 u^2$ is real, positive, its square-root is real positive too, right?

Comment: @user929304: Not exactly $-$ its square root is real, but not necessarily positive.

Comment: ty, very elegant approach!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $5/3 + 1/3 = 2$. Think about [what multiplying complex numbers does to their polar angles.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Multiplication_and_division_in_polar_form)

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as stating $u = \pm \sqrt 3 e^{\frac{\pi i}3}$ so $zu = \pm 4\sqrt 3 e^{5\frac{\pi i}3 +\frac{\pi i}3 } = \pm 4 \sqrt 3 e^{2 {\pi i}} =  \pm 4 \sqrt 3  \in \mathbb{R}$